# Erro no JSON com Palavras acentuadas

Tags: php, json

Eu tenho um código em PHP, que imprime valores do banco de dados em json.

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

    require_once "conexao.php";

    class Modelo {

      private $pdo;

      function Modelo() {
        $conexao = new Conexao();
        $this->pdo = $conexao->conect();
      }

      public function listaClientes() {

        $sql = "SELECT * from cliente";
        $sql = $this->pdo->query($sql);

        $lc = array();

        foreach($sql->fetchAll() as $cliente) {
          $lc[] = $cliente['nome'];
        }

        return json_encode($lc);
      }

    }

    $m = new Modelo();

    echo $m->listaClientes();

    echo json_last_error();

    ?>
```

Ele roda normal, mas caso eu coloque algum valor com acento ele não mostra nada, apenas retorna o valor 5 da função *`json_last_error`*, que no caso é erro com relação ao UTF8

- **5 = JSON_ERROR_UTF8: erro na codificação UTF-8 da string JSON;**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu banco já está com a codificação correta, como posso resolver esse problema?

Comment: Já tentou alterar o `application/json`... por `text/html`?

Comment: Como é um arquivo php, acho que o MIME pode estar errado.

Comment: @dvd troquei para "text/html" mas não resolveu.
Oque seria MME?

Comment: MIME é o tipo do arquivo

Comment: return json_encode($lc, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

Comment: já coloquei JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE, mesmo assim continua dando o mesmo erro. @Guilherme

Comment: Mas a conexão mysqli (no php), também está como utf8? Algo como `mysqli_set_charset($conexao, "utf8")`

Comment: Eu to usando PDO para fazer a conexão @Juven_v

Comment: Não tinha visto. Mas a ideia é a mesma. Aqui no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361459/php-pdo-charset-set-names) tem explicando como configurar com pdo

Comment: Era isso mesmo @Juven_v, deu certo aqui